# Send data from server to client - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jinja2

I need to call some python function and show its results (actually a couple of *list* objects) in the *div id="places"* section. I'm trying to do this in Javascript function *show_sec()* but i can't find out how to catch the data from server and process it on client.

My task is really simple and basic but since it's my first web project I need some help with ajax. Please, help me.

This is a part of my code:

.html

```
{% include "header.html" ignore missing %}

 <!-- contents of nearest banks page -->
    <section id="ask_user">
            <div id="question">Разрешить приложению определить Ваше место расположения для нахождения ближайших банков?</div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <input type="button" name="yes" value="Да, разрешить" onclick="show_sec()"/>
                <input type="button" name="no" value="Нет, не разрешать" onclick="dnt_show_sec()"/>
            </div>
    </section>

        <section id="allowed" style="display:none;">
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
            <div id="nearest_banks">
                <form action="/nearest_banks/radius" method="get" id="send_radius">
                  Курс ближайших банков на сегодня в радиусе
                  <input type="text" name="radius" id="radius" size="5" value={{radius}} >
                  <input type="submit" class="button" value="V">
                   метров
                </form>
                <div id="check"> {{output}}</div>
                <div id="places"> </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="not_allowed" style="display:none;">
            <div class="question"> Приложение не имеет возможности определить близ лежащие банки.<div>
        </section>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

   /* frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serializeArray(),
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                $("#check").html("OK!!!");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $("#check").html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); */

    function show_sec() {
        document.getElementById('allowed').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('ask_user').style.display = 'none';
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/nearest_banks/radius",
        }).success(function(data) {
            $("#places").html(data);
            /*alert ("OK !!!"); */
        });

    }

    function dnt_show_sec() {
        document.getElementById('not_allowed').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('ask_user').style.display = 'none';
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button#yes").click(function(){
            //alert("demo_test");
            $("section#allowed").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

python function i try to call:

```
*def get(self):
        default_radius = 1000
        radius = get_radius(self)
        exceptions = [u'', 'error', 0]                    # invalid values for radius
        if any([radius in exceptions]):
            radius = default_radius
            #warning = "Вы ввели неверный радиус. Система автоматически заменила его на стандартный."
            output = radius                               # заменить на вывод банков
        else:
            #warning = ''
            output = radius                               # заменить на вывод банков
        names, location = Findplaces(self, radius)  
        body_values = {
          'names': names,
          'location': location,
          'radius': radius,
          'output': output,
          #'warning': warning,
        }
        template = jinja_env.get_template('nearest_banks.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(body_values))*
```

**In short** my goal is to display *names* and *location* in the tag *div id="places"* after clicking on *Yes* button.

Or maybe i can initiate displaying specific tags from server side by using jinja2 in my python function.

Please, help me. I've spent time on it still can't get it working nicely. Thanks in advance !

**EDIT:**

When I click on *Yes* button the show_sec function loads *section with id allowed*. 
**The problem:** the action in form is not processed. So Only html is shown but data from server is not received.

Comment: Have you checked developers console? What is the response of ajax query? What is the value of `data` in `show_sec`?

Comment: you haven't explained what is or isn't working, or what specific problem you have

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. u_mulder, data contains html code ... Like all the tags of the html I showed above

Comment: Maybe your `places` div initially hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Since the url is "/nearest_banks/radius" and it's a get, try opening that in a browser to see what appears. You may need to view source on the page returned to view it properly. You should verify functionality of the web service first, that it returns something, and returns the correct thing.

Following that, in your show_sec function, do trial and error to see what happens. If you move the requested content to the same path as the executing page, does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, I've made some check. My server function works well, I just can't find out how to display its results using jQuery ...

Comment: I use pure javascript myself. Try instantiating an xmlhttp object and fetching the content with that. You may be able to see errors better that way. Then, if you want to retain jquery you will know what changes to introduce.

Comment: @dmcdivitt you can use [jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {});](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to see errors. And, by the way, your answer looks like comment, not like an answer.

Comment: I do not yet have sufficient points to post comments and can only post answers